# FullText Search with FreeText but only return records that contain all words of an expression, except those on stopword list

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

i´ve searched for a solution for a while now. Anyway I can not come up with a way that returns me the recordset I want.

I have a table full of different texts as a collection of all texts used in a HMI software.
Now when a user creates a new text I want to check if a similar text already exists in the table.

I´ve come so far to find FullTextSearch on MS SQL Server should be the best way to do this. My Problem is the following: 
When I use **FreeText** on a new text that should be checked for similar values I get way to many results. Every record is listed that contains even only one of the relevant words in my search string.

**Example:**

Search text:

- `Deceleration Linear Motor Transfer to Top`

Values that should be found:

- `'Deceleration linear motor transfer top'`
- `'Deceleration linear motor handover to top'`

Values that should not be found:

- `'Accelearion linear motor handover to top'`
- `'linear motor handover to top'`

---

So I want it to work just like **FreeText** is working (with INFLECTIONAL and THESAURUS comparison), but only records that contain **all words** in the search string, **except** those who are on the stopword list (so fill words are also ignored).

I thought about using **Contains** in combination with **Formsof** for every single word in my search string. But then it does not ignore those words on the stopword list.

I hope I was able to specify my problem properly and hope someone can help me with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might also run into this kinda problem. I solved it myself by now with the sledgehammer approach. 
I just concat all words in my search expression with

```
(Formsof(... Thesaurus, *Word1* ) OR Formsof(... INFLECTIONAL *Word1*)) AND  
(Formsof(... Thesaurus, *Word2* ) OR Formsof(... INFLECTIONAL *Word2*))
```

For the stopwords I skip those words manually by checking each word if it is listed before adding it to my where string.
This article helped me a lot with getting the correct language id for the selected column in the code.

[Some Useful Full Text Index Stoplist Related Queries](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/some-useful-full-text-index-stoplist-related-queries/)